# Access Silverlights collection from javascript

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I have Silverlight class embedded into page, in App.xaml.cs this component registered to allow calls SL methods from javascript and it is working right.

But now I would like to access not method, but collection.
For example, I have public property

```
[ScriptableMember]
ICollection<FileInfo> Files {get;set;}
```

At the runtime i checked accessibility of Files member:

```
silverlightPlugin.Content.Uploader.Files    | {...}  | Object
```

defined and has type of Object

But when I trying to call any of following:

```
silverlightPlugin.Content.Uploader.Files.Count
silverlightPlugin.Content.Uploader.Files.Count()
silverlightPlugin.Content.Uploader.Files.get_Count
silverlightPlugin.Content.Uploader.Files.get_Count()
```

I've got an exception "Input string was not in a correct format".

Is there any way to access collections from JS or I need to implement special method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible. I using function to get required data.